# Given a datetime, calculate the lat/lon coordinates where the sun is directly overhead

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, astronomy, orbital-mechanics

Some variants of this question have been asked before, but not this exact one. So here goes:

Given a particular point in time, how do I calculate the lat/lon coordinates of a point on the surface of the Earth where the Sun is directly overhead?

I can get the declination and the right ascension, and those numbers seem accurate. It should be a piece of cake from here but it's getting late and I'm completely lost.

Any help?

Comment: I think there is a question of what precision you need... At some point the fact that the earths orbit is elliptical not circular becomes important for example...

Comment: Just something approximate. We can assume the orbit to be circular and the Earth to be a sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are assuming earth to be a sphere, you can assume latitude to be a sinusoidal function of day of the year (more precisely cosine. Normalize 365 days to 2pi and when day = june 21st, the value is equal to 0).

Longitude will depend on the time of the day. Normalize time so that one day = 360 degrees and offset accordingly.

Details:

AT present tropic of cancer is at latitude L = 23° 26′ 16″

So, Latitude = L*cos( (X-a)/b ), where a=June21st, b = 365.25/2pi .

Longitude = (time -  t0 ) *360 /24, where time is current time in hours(UTC), t0 is the offset.

Comment: Neat! Especially the longitude calculation. Not sure about the latitude though: why June 25th? I thought the summer solstice was closer the the 21st.

Comment: @martona I was not sure about the exact date. Now I have changed it to 21st. Is that your only concern?

Comment: But then again... I don't really need to calculate the latitude. I have the declination which happens to be the very same thing.